# How to set color legend manually for python plotly open street map

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, openstreetmap, plotly-python

is there any way to set color legend manually for python plotly open street map.
For example: instead of the legend color range , need to set the first 5 values: Red and next 5 blue and then yellow.
[image]

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
df = px.data.carshare()
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="centroid_lat", lon="centroid_lon",     color="peak_hour", size="car_hours",
                  color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire, size_max=15, zoom=10)
fig.show()
```

The legend should be like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you take a look [here](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale)?

Comment: it works @Bastian. Thanks a lot

Comment: Were you able to customize the color bar? I tried to customize it, but I couldn't get a continuous color and green. I encourage you to self-answer with your own solution.

Comment: Ya sure, Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `color_continuous_scale` parameter in `px.scatter_mapbox()` like this:

```
color_scale = [(0, 'blue'), (.25, 'blue'), (.25, 'green'), (.5, 'green'),\
           (0.5, 'red'), (0.75, 'red'), (0.75, 'yellow'), (1, 'yellow')]
color_continuous_scale = color_scale
```

For more details, you can check out [this link](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/)

Answer (score 1):

```
access_token = 'Your Token'
px.set_mapbox_access_token(access_token)
import plotly.express as px
#px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
df = px.data.carshare()
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="centroid_lat", lon="centroid_lon",     color="peak_hour", size="car_hours",
color_continuous_scale=[(0.00, "red"),   (0.33, "red"),
                                                     (0.33, "green"), (0.66, "green"),
                                                     (0.66, "blue"),  (1.00, "blue")]                  
, size_max=15, zoom=10)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I had mistakenly castified it with `color_discrete_sequence`.

Comment: `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(tickvals=[0,6,12,18,23]))` I just need to add this and I'm done.